# LaTeX compiles <" a> to <ä>

Tags: german

I write a German text in case that matters and use these packages:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{cite}
```

... starting a document

```
\section{Einleitung}
Idee des "guten Willens" an
```

... there comes more text

When I compile this, the output reads `Idee des "guten Willensän` instead of `Idee des "guten Willens" an`

I heard LaTeX changes `"a` to `ä` automatically, so this could be the reason of my error. How can I turn this feature off in case it is the problem?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but in general, you should use single quotes (grave `` and normal ' ' ) to denote quoted material.

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  Quotation marks in LaTeX should be indicated by `\`\`` and `''` and *not* `"`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Your quotes are for english, not german.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I learn something new each day.  Thanks!

Comment: The space after an active duoble quote (") is ignored. This is a feature, not a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I understand now I managed the whole quotation thing in a wrong way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here some variants to insert (german) quotes: I prefer the variants which make use of csquotes. Also don't load ucs or use utf8x unless you really need it.

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeAutoQuote{«}{»}  % or \MakeAutoQuote {„}{“}  

\begin{document}
% ngerman shorthands:
"`Text mit \glq einem inneren Zitat\grq\ und weiter"'

%ngerman commands:
\glqq Text mit \glq einem inneren Zitat\grq\ und weiter\grqq\ und weiter

%direct utf8-input
„Text“

%with csquotes:

%1. \enquote (inner quotes uses automatically single quote signs):
\enquote{Text mit \enquote{einem innerem Zitat} und weiter} und weiter

%2. with the \MakeAutoQuote set above:
«Text mit «einem innerem Zitat» und weiter» und weiter

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! For a beginner like me this is really helpful